# Specify minlen to specific user

Tags: password, pam

OS: Debian 10.10

Hi all,

Can I specify a `minlen` option for "user2" but not for "user1"?

Currently, my `/etc/pam.d/common-password.conf` contains:

```
password    requisite           pam_pwquality.so minlen=6 user = user2
```

But the `minlen=6` argument is in use for all users.

Comment: is user2 a unique exception ?

Comment: @terdon, Ok I understand.

Comment: @MC68020, today is the unique exception.

Answer (score 0):

Today I declared a long password contains 23 characters for "user2".

I don't like this solution because when he renew the password he don't have a policy/rule to deny the specific minlen for this specific user.